# numpy issue with concatenating arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am porting some Matlab code to python and I have the following statement in Matlab:

```
cross([pt1,1]-[pp,0],[pt2,1]-[pp,0]);
```

`pt1`, `pt2` and `pp` are 2D points.

So, my corresponding python code looks as follows:

```
np.cross(np.c_[pt1 - pp, 1], np.c_[pt2 - pp, 1])
```

The points are defined as:

```
pt1  = np.asarray((440.0, 59.0))
pt2 = np.asarray((-2546.23, 591.03))
pp = np.asarray([563.,  456.5])
```

When I execute the statement with the cross product, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

So looking at some other posts, here I thought I would try `np.column_stack` but I get the same error:

```
np.cross(np.column_stack((pt1 - pp, 1)), np.column_stack((pt2 - pp, 1)))
```

Comment: I got the following error: `ValueError: incompatible dimensions for cross product
(dimension must be 2 or 3)`

Comment: Sorry I had some typos. I  edited it now.

Comment: **pt1 - pp = array([-123. , -397.5])**, are you hoping to get **array([-123. , -397.5, 1])**?

Comment: @Indominus yes, precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
np.cross(np.append(pt1-pp, 1), np.append(pt2-pp, 1))
```

Comment: *facepalm* :)))

Comment: If you do this type of vector/matrix manipulations a lot, be prepared that the migration from Matlab to Python would make your life a little worse, especially bench-marked to the newer versions of Matlab. Python's matrix syntax is not as concise, also the way numpy handles matrix dimensions is less intuitive than Matlab. Your question is a typical example of numpy not able to easily differentiate a *nx1* matrix and a *1xn* matrix

Comment: While I know what you are driving at, I'd differ in how you phrase it.  `numpy` is perfectly able to distinguish between (1,n) and (n,1) arrays.  But it also has (n,) arrays, which apparently are a mystery to someone raised on MATLAB :)  And it also has real scalars (not the pseudo 1x1 MATLAB ones).  I tend to discourage the use of `np.append` because it is often misused.  Here, though, it is useful, turning the scalar `1` into a 1d array that can be concatenated with the rest.

Comment: You are absolutely right. What I meant by "easily" is just I like to write `arr[i, :]` instead of `arr[[i], :]`. Matlab defaults array dimension to 2 (unless above 2). It is true that it is pseudo, but we humans see and do things in 2-dim. Sorry, I'll stop here before I go completely off topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `np.r_` instead it works:

```
In [40]: np.cross(np.r_[pt1 - pp, 1], np.r_[pt2 - pp, 1])
Out[40]: array([-5.32030000e+02, -2.98623000e+03, -1.25246611e+06])
```

Your `pt1` and `pp` are (2,) arrays.  To add a `1` to them you need to use a 1d concatenate, `np.r_` for 'row', as opposed to `columns`.

There are lots of ways of constructing a 3 element array:

```
In [43]: np.r_[pt1 - pp, 1]
Out[43]: array([-123. , -397.5,    1. ])
In [44]: np.append(pt1 - pp, 1)
Out[44]: array([-123. , -397.5,    1. ])
In [45]: np.concatenate((pt1 - pp, [1]))
Out[45]: array([-123. , -397.5,    1. ])
```

`concatenate` is the base operation.  The others tweak the `1` to produce a 1d array that can be joined with the (2,) shape array to make a (3,).

Concatenate turns all of its inputs into arrays, if they aren't already: `np.concatenate((pt1 - pp, np.array([1])))`.

Note that `np.c_` docs say it is the equivalent of

```
np.r_['-1,2,0', index expression]
```

That initial string expression is a bit complicated.  The key point is it tries to concatenate 2d arrays (whereas your `pt1` is 1d).

It is like `column_stack, joining`n(2,1)`arrays to make a`(2,n)` array.

```
In [48]: np.c_[pt1, pt2]
Out[48]: 
array([[  440.  , -2546.23],
       [   59.  ,   591.03]])
In [50]: np.column_stack((pt1, pt2))
Out[50]: 
array([[  440.  , -2546.23],
       [   59.  ,   591.03]])
```

In MATLAB everything has at least 2 dimensions, and because it is Fortran based, the outer dimensions are last.  So in a sense its most natural 'vector' shape is n x 1, a column matrix.  `numpy` is built on Python, with a natural interface to its scalars and nested lists.  Order is `c` based; the initial dimensions are outer most.  So `numpy` code can have true scalars (Python numbers without shape or size), or arrays with 0 or more dimensions.  A 'vector' most naturally has shape `(n,)` (a 1 element tuple).  It can easily be reshaped to (1,n) or (n,1) if needed.

If you want a (3,1) array (instead of (3,) shaped), you'd need to use some sort of 'vertical' concatenation, joining a (2,1) array with a (1,1):

```
In [51]: np.r_['0,2,0', pt1-pp, 1]
Out[51]: 
array([[-123. ],
       [-397.5],
       [   1. ]])
In [53]: np.vstack([(pt1-pp)[:,None], 1])
Out[53]: 
array([[-123. ],
       [-397.5],
       [   1. ]])
```

(But `np.cross` wants (n,3) or (3,) arrays, not (3,1)!)

```
In [58]: np.cross(np.r_['0,2,0', pt1-pp, 1], np.r_['0,2,0', pt2-pp, 1])
...
ValueError: incompatible dimensions for cross product
(dimension must be 2 or 3)
```

To get around this specify an axis:

```
In [59]: np.cross(np.r_['0,2,0', pt1-pp, 1], np.r_['0,2,0', pt2-pp, 1], axis=0)
Out[59]: 
array([[-5.32030000e+02],
       [-2.98623000e+03],
       [-1.25246611e+06]])
```

Study `np.cross` if you want an example of manipulating dimensions. In this `axis=0` case it transposes the arrays so they are (1,3) and then does the calculation.